# Pool connection is closing after 30sec

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using select * from sys.dm_exec_connections for seeing active pooling connections. When i'm create a new sql pool connection through tcp(wifi) it creates my new connection as image below.

[image: Img]

The problem is that if wifi will close for 30 sec, then it destroys my connection.
Why is this happening? I have set min pool size =5 in connection string.

```
 Server=myServerAddress;min pool size =5;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
```

Password=myPassword;

After 30sec

#[image: Img2]

Answer (score 0):

`Min Pool Size` is not the time a connection stays active, it's (minimum) how many connections to use for pooling.

You want `Connection Lifetime = 300` (for 5 minutes)

Here's the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: It didn't solved my problem. I think sql keep alive it closes my connection automatically after 30 sec

Comment: How many connections to use for pooling has to do for each client?